# CoreGraphics Library Leaking in iOS4 and not iOS3?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios, ios4

I am using instruments to check for memory leaks in my app.. iOS 3.1.x doesnt show any leaks.
However, when I do the same test on iOS4 iPhone I am getting leaks from CoreGraphics library.

Did anyone had similar problem? is it problem in the OS itself?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With so few details, it's hard to say exactly. I have, however, experienced SDK version-dependent leaks and other misfeatures with iOS code, comparing 3.0 to 3.1 and 3.1 to 4.x. I think the iOS SDKs are relatively buggy compared to what I expected (very polished Apple APIs).